How to capture error messages during binder creation/initialization
Using Spring Boot 3.3.6 and Spring Cloud 2023.0.3, this minimal code works great for consuming messages from a Kafka topic:
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class TestApplication {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        }
    
        @Bean(name = "receivePurple")
        public Consumer<String> receivePurple() {
            return msg -> System.out.println("received purple message: " + msg);
        }
    }

application.yml:
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: receivePurple
    stream:
      bindings:
        receivePurple-in-0:
          binder: blueKafka
          destination: purpleTopic
          group: purpleGroup
      binders:
        blueKafka:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9011
                      autoCreateTopics: false
                      autoAddPartitions: false
                      configuration:
                        allow.auto.create.topics: false
                        key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                        value.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

However, during the initial deployment, there was a typo:
    key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serializatoin.StringDeserializer

that took many painstaking hours to troubleshoot, mostly because the error message didn't give any indication of the underlying problem:
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Cannot initialize binder checking the topic (purpleTopic):
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionsForTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:685) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-4.1.3.jar:4.1.3]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain partition information for the topic purpleTopic

To avoid this troubleshooting headache in the future, I thought it would be easy to update the configuration to capture error messages, but I can't find anything that gives me access to the error.  The documentation talks about capturing binding errors:
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.receivePurple-in-0.error-handler-definition=myErrorHandler
spring.cloud.stream.default.error-handler-definition=myErrorHandler

but doesn't have anything about binder errors.
What can be configured (logging, channel, interceptor, ??) to capture errors that happen during binder creation/initialization?
